# Save to Drive Button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Подскажите где найти пример как сделать 
Save to Drive Button на React, никак не могу найти. Спасибо.

Comment: Save to Drive Button - кнопка сохранения на google диск?

Comment: Да верно, но нам нужно использовать кастомную кнопку, а не кнопку от гугл